# Returning exact matches by checking preceding succeeding character of needle in haystack

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I return a match only when characters like `[a-zA-zäöåÄÖÅ]` do not directly appear one place before **and** after the match in the search string.

Say for example I'm looking for `on` in a string.

The following examples should evaluate to:

```
False: "luonto - nature" because uont
True: "olla (on, ovat, ole )" because (on,
False: "kevät (season)" because son)
```

Thanks.

Comment: You can give this a go: `[^a-zA-zäöåÄÖÅ]on[^a-zA-zäöåÄÖÅ]` -- This can be used in checking for a match, but it doesn't return the input search. https://regex101.com/ that is a good site for building and testing regex strings

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick.

Comment: Would there be a way to check when `on` was the first word in the string? Like `on something something`.

Comment: You can see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this needs more than just a comment, so I am making this a proper answer.

As per my comment, you can use `[^a-zA-zäöåÄÖÅ]on[^a-zA-zäöåÄÖÅ]` to check for the clause stated in the question of the question.

If you want to be more specific about `on` being at the start of the end of the string you can make it `(^|[^a-zA-zäöåÄÖÅ])on([^a-zA-zäöåÄÖÅ]|$)` which will test that:

- `^` [the start of the string]
- **or** [`|`]
- `[^a-zA-zäöåÄÖÅ]`[None(`^`) of the list(`a-zA-zäöåÄÖÅ`)]
- comes directly before the string literal `on`

**AND**

- directly after the string literal `on`
- `[^a-zA-zäöåÄÖÅ]`[None(`^`) of the list(`a-zA-zäöåÄÖÅ`)]
- **or** [`|`]
- `$` [the end of the string]

As I mentioned in the comment as well, a great site for learning and testing regex is [Regex 101](https://regex101.com/)

Hope this helps